# Microsoft Graph - CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A

Tags: c++, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am requesting access token from Microsoft Graph using this procedure:

1. I request access to the following scopes:

`User.Read.All openid profile email offline_access https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send`

2. After the consent screen in web browser, the redirection occurs and the codes are sent to temporary localhost web server running on user's PC.
3. The `code` received is exchanged for **access_token** and **refresh_token**
4. When I try to query Microsoft Graph for user's profile I query:

GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

Header of the GET request contains:

`Authorization: Bearer token-here-all-in-one-line`

But I get the resulting JSON:

`"InvalidAuthenticationToken"`

`"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A"`

I would normally assume the token is not correct, but I tested the same token from C++ app and a small PHP app, and I always test the same error. To be sure that it is not the wrong token, I deliberately modify it to a wrong token and then I get:

`"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217"`

After googling - `8004920A` means "token rejected" (the error I have problem with) and `80049217` means "malformed token" so that is consistent with me deliberately inserting false data as token.

So I would assume that the token is correct but Microsoft Graph rejects it to query user profile information which is consented and approved.

I have tested the token on IMAP and SMTP access and there it works - mails are sent and received, so the `access_token` is definitely good.

Any ideas why Microsoft Graph rejects my attempt to query user profile?

Do I need to enable something when registering application in AzureAD portal?

I am doing this from C++ or from PHP so I don't think the code is of relevance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nikolay has stated, the tokens for Graph and Outlook can't be mixed. And Microsoft has designed it poorly so that `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` for example can't be used for IMAP access - the access_token simply won't work unless the `https://outlook.office.com/` prefix is added.

But - I found **another way**, which works for just reading the user's profile and email address which is by decoding the `id_token`. As Microsoft documentation states - `openid` `profile` and `email` scopes will work with both Graph and Outlook. `profile` token can be used to extract the information about user's profile.

As explained on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens

`id_token` contains information such as email address, name etc.

A sample ID token from their page is:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFMVE16YWtpaGlSbGFfOHoyQkVKVlhlV01xbyJ9.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.1AFWW-Ck5nROwSlltm7GzZvDwUkqvhSQpm55TQsmVo9Y59cLhRXpvB8n-55HCr9Z6G_31_UbeUkoz612I2j_Sm9FFShSDDjoaLQr54CreGIJvjtmS3EkK9a7SJBbcpL1MpUtlfygow39tFjY7EVNW9plWUvRrTgVk7lYLprvfzw-CIqw3gHC-T7IK_m_xkr08INERBtaecwhTeN4chPC4W3jdmw_lIxzC48YoQ0dB1L9-ImX98Egypfrlbm0IBL5spFzL6JDZIRRJOu8vecJvj1mq-IUhGt0MacxX8jdxYLP-KUu2d9MbNKpCKJuZ7p8gwTL5B7NlUdh_dmSviPWrw
```

The token consists of 3 parts - **header**, **payload** and the **signature**. They are separated by a dot. That's a standard JWT (JSON Web Token) See details at - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token

After separating them and then base64 decoding each (the signature doesn't give anything useful after decoding) the result is:

**1) The header**

```json
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "1LTMzakihiRla_8z2BEJVXeWMqo"
}
```

**2) The payload**

Payload which contains the user info. Additional information can be extracted by adding **Optional claims** when registering app in Azure AD - (**Token configuration** in the menu on the left).

[image: Token Configuration in Azure AD]

```json
{
    "ver": "2.0",
    "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9122040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0",
    "sub": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIkzqFVrSaSaFHy782bbtaQ",
    "aud": "6cb04018-a3f5-46a7-b995-940c78f5aef3",
    "exp": 1536361411,
    "iat": 1536274711,
    "nbf": 1536274711,
    "name": "Abe Lincoln",
    "preferred_username": "AbeLi@microsoft.com",
    "oid": "00000000-0000-0000-66f3-3332eca7ea81",
    "tid": "9122040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad",
    "nonce": "123523",
    "aio": "Df2UVXL1ix!lMCWMSOJBcFatzcGfvFGhjKv8q5g0x732dR5MB5BisvGQO7YWByjd8iQDLq!eGbIDakyp5mnOrcdqHeYSnltepQmRp6AIZ8jY"
}
```

**3) The signature**

For verification purposes only.

```json
1AFWW-Ck5nROwSlltm7GzZvDwUkqvhSQpm55TQsmVo9Y59cLhRXpvB8n-55HCr9Z6G_31_UbeUkoz612I2j_Sm9FFShSDDjoaLQr54CreGIJvjtmS3EkK9a7SJBbcpL1MpUtlfygow39tFjY7EVNW9plWUvRrTgVk7lYLprvfzw-CIqw3gHC-T7IK_m_xkr08INERBtaecwhTeN4chPC4W3jdmw_lIxzC48YoQ0dB1L9-ImX98Egypfrlbm0IBL5spFzL6JDZIRRJOu8vecJvj1mq-IUhGt0MacxX8jdxYLP-KUu2d9MbNKpCKJuZ7p8gwTL5B7NlUdh_dmSviPWrw
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the case, but it may be. You cannot use the same token for graph access and another API acccess (such as Outlook REST api, in your case). Meaning, you cannot mix scopes from different namespaces. Not sure why ("by design"?), you just can't. You need two separate tokens.

I faced similar issue with SharePoint REST api access (so may not be 100% sure it is also true for Outlook as well, but probably it is). I used a relatively easy way out - [exchanging the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) requested for `openid profile email offline_access` for token for `https://outlook.office.com/...` on my server (using the `on_behalf_of` flow).

If you don't really need the graph scope `User.Read.All` you could also try simply removing that one from your first authorization call that obtains the token.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is one solution for sure, but I found another which is better for me at least and doesn't require exchanging the token. See my reply.